# Integration of Blogengine into existing websites

Tags: blogengine.net

I am trying to integrate Blogengine into my existing .net website.

I found this page on stackoverflow, [Is there a stable ASP.NET blogging control (designed for integration within existing site)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697748/is-there-a-stable-asp-net-blogging-control-designed-for-integration-within-exis)

step4 says, "4:Add the Blog Engine.core project in the Web Application. Build Blog Engine.core and add reference from your web project to “BlogEngine.Core.dll”.

What am I specifically supposed to do in this step?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Download the BlogEngine from http://blogengine.codeplex.com/releases. You should take the source version. It contains: BlogEngine.Core, BlogEngine.Net and BlogEngine.Tests.

You should take the project "BlogEngine.Core" and copy it to your solution, and reference it from the website where your blog is.